# StoredProcedure msdb.dbo.sp_help_job causes SQL Server Deadlocks

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, deadlock, sql-agent-job

I'm currently making minor changes in some of our AgentJobs (adding new steps, renaming schedules, etc.).

From time to time it happens, that when I save the changes from an AgentJob, a deadlock occurs. We have a tool called SQLSentry, which sends me an e-mail about these locks with the following informations:

```
[Deadlock Victim Information]:
SPID [ecid]: 89 [0]
Host: [...]
Application: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
Database: msdb
Login: [...]
Log Used: 0
Deadlock Priority: 0
Wait Time: 2985
Transaction Start Time: 15.03.2016 15:56:19
Last Batch Start Time: 15.03.2016 15:56:19
Last Batch Completion Time: 15.03.2016 15:56:19
Mode/Type: S
Status: suspended
Isolation Level: read committed (2)
Text Data:
    at msdb.dbo.sp_get_composite_job_info line 78
      INSERT INTO @job_execution_state
  SELECT xpr.job_id,
         xpr.last_run_date,
         xpr.last_run_time,
         xpr.job_state,
         sjs.step_id,
         sjs.step_name,
         xpr.current_retry_attempt,
         xpr.next_run_date,
         xpr.next_run_time,
         xpr.next_run_schedule_id
  FROM @xp_results                          xpr
       LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps sjs ON ((xpr.job_id = sjs.job_i
Transaction Count: 0
SPID: [...]
Transaction Name: INSERT
Transaction ID: [...]
Database ID: [...]
Wait Resource: KEY: 4:72057594057392128 (b17adeaeb74a)
Lock Timeout: 4294967295
Input Buffer:
exec msdb.dbo.sp_help_job @job_id='0435b309-1178-4b60-a937-435cb9e299ff'
ECID: 0
```

I don't know what to do about these deadlocks. It doesn't seem, that any data would be lost, because of them. And also the don't appear immediately, after I press the "Save" button. The information from the deadlock above I received about 15 minutes later.

Any ideas or similar experiences? It's really painful, because I can't really reproduce the error on purpose.

Greetings, nDust

Comment: If you're using SQLSentry, you should also be able to see what it is deadlocking with-- so what is it?

Comment: Regarding SQL Sentry, those are the "Waiters Statement":  
`msdb.dbo.sp_delete_jobstep  
 UPDATE msdb.dbo.sysjobs  
    SET version_number = version_number + 1,  
        date_modified = GETDATE()  
    WHERE (job_id = @job_id)  
  
adhoc  
 EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_jobstep @job_id=N'0435b309-1178-4b60-a937-435cb9e299ff', @step_id=1`